# Crear tablespace en Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Saludos quisiera saber la manera de como  se debe crear un tablespace y una tabla que almacene sus datos en el tablespace recién creado

Answer (score 1):

Para crear un nuevo tablespace:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE `nuevo_tablespace` ADD DATAFILE 'nuevo_tablespace.ibd'
```

Con eso se crea un archivo `ibd` bajo el mismo directorio donde está el tablespace general (`/var/lib/mysql/`). Puedes especificar una ruta absoluta si quieres

```
CREATE TABLESPACE `nuevo_tablespace` ADD DATAFILE '/home/ubuntu/nuevo_tablespace.ibd'
```

Para crear una tabla en el nuevo tablespace:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    nombre VARCHAR(128), 
    apellido VARCHAR(128)
) TABLESPACE=`nuevo_tablespace`;
```

En todo caso te comento que por defecto, la versión actual de MySQL trae activada la opción [innodb_file_per_table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) con la cual cada tabla tiene su propio tablespace.